# What defines the log type (Default, Alert, Error, Critical, etc) on logs out of a Cloud Run container instance?

Tags: debugging, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

I have an `express` server that is hosted on Cloud Run / Docker container.

This is the screen where we can view logs that come out of the deployed instance.

[image]

What defines the "type" of the log message: as in `Alert, Critical, Error, Warning, Debug, Info, Notice and Default`

If I log with `console.error` will it show up as an `Error` ?

What is the documentation on this subject?

---

**UPDATE:** Trying to log an error with the type `Error`

```
const logError = (msg: string | Error) => console.error(`[test:error] ${msg}`);

const testError = () : void => {
  try {
    throw new Error("TEST ERROR");
  }
  catch(err) {
    const someError = new Error("HELLO ERROR");
    console.log(someError);
    console.error(someError);
    logError(err);
    logError("ERROR STRING MSG");
  }
};
```

These were the results:

[image]

Not a single log with the type `Error`. Is this not supposed to be triggered by our code? When should it happen?

I'd like to filter logged messages from my `catch` blocks in some situations and I was hoping to filter for the `Error` log type. I guess I'll have to add the `[error]` string flag and filter for that.

How do people usually handle this?

Comment: If you wish to set the "type" then you will need to integrate logging into your code. Stackdriver is very easy to add.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks. Could you point a documentation on how to implement that?

Comment: Google search `stackdriver node.js`.

Comment: @JohnHanley is right, a quick search and you can find [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs). You need to format correctly your logs to be ingested by fluentd. The proposed lib help you in this task

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere just tried to install `bunyan`, but it seems to be a pain to work on Windows. Must install `Visual Studio` and a bunch of other tools + configs. Will try to use the [Logging Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs#using_the_cloud_client_library_directly) directly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just install and use the Stackdriver node.js library if your goal is to send logs to Google Stackdriver (Operations Logging).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install and use the Stackdriver node.js library if your goal is to send logs to Google Stackdriver (Operations Logging).